# Can we use Spring instead of CDI and Weld while using Helidon Microprofile Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, helidon

I wish to use Helidon for a service but was wondering if it supports Spring as my app is built using Spring

The examples for helidon are built with CDI and Weld

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

Helidon has two modes:

- Helidon SE
- Helidon MP

Of these two, Helidon MP implements [MicroProfile](https://microprofile.io/) which in turn implements the most important parts of the Java EE 8 standard.

Spring is a proprietary product. It is not the goal of Helidon to implement Spring. If you want to implement your application using Spring, use Spring.